# XML Schema use the ref keyword for refering to a attribute from another namespace

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I have a problem creating a XML-Schema file. I want to define some attributes which should refer to elements outside the current namespace. I am using PyCharm & there you have the great possibility to include a schema for checking the current xml file, and when you fill in some tags it auto-completes the definition for you. This feature i want to use to reduce the overhead of typing each parameter from ground of. Of course i dont want to misuse the xml schema. 
I´m open for any suggestions when they´re applicable. And i only displayed an part of my whoöe documents.

(content of the .xsd):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
       targetNamespace="https://www.w3schools.com"
       xmlns="https://www.w3schools.com"
       elementFormDefault="qualified"
xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
>

<xs:complexType name="Parameters">
    <xi:attribute ref="xi:href" use="required"/>
    <xi:attribute ref="xi:xpointer" use="required"/>
    <xi:attribute ref="xi:parse" use="required"/>
    <xi:attribute ref="xi:href" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

What i actually want, is to define the attributes of the node parameters by an schema definition. So a correct xml file should look like:

```
<Parameters>
        <xi:include href="some.xml" xpointer="xpointer(//root)" parse="xml">
            <xi:fallback>Sorry, some.xml not available</xi:fallback>
        </xi:include>
    </Parameters>
```

without the filled in values for each attribute. Is there any possibility? or is that not possible due to restrictions to including and checking schemas? Thanks for your help.